# Node doesn't exit automatically once a listener is set on stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node.js doesn't exit automatically once a listener is set on `process.stdin`, even if that listener is later removed.

Example:

```js
const listener = ()=>{};

process.stdin.on("data", listener);
process.stdin.off("data", listener);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a live listener for incoming data on stdin and that stream stays open (isn't naturally closed by coming to the end of its source), then node.js has no idea whether there is more data that may be coming or not so it keeps the process alive.

Here are several things you can do to get the app to shutdown:

1. Call `process.exit(0)` to manually shut it down.
2. Call `process.stdin.unref()` to tell nodejs not to wait for this stream.
3. Call `process.stdin.pause()`.

It appears that once you've attached the `data` event handler, removing it doesn't allow the app to exit (per some reports I read) so you have to resort to one of these other options.

FYI, here's a little test app where you can experiment with what causes the app to shut-down or not.  I've verified that all three of these options work.

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
    if (data.toString() === 'x') {
        process.stdin.pause();      // will cause process to exit
    }
});

process.stdin.resume();

process.stdout.write("Type characters, 'x' to exit\n");
```

Comment: Just wanted to verify, that when you want to listen to stdin in a script, you reference the socket when you assign a listener to it. If you don't unreference the socket when the script closes the process stays open. Calling `process.stdin.unref()` in that script will let the process end without exiting prior to a parent caller finishing. *Calling unref() on a socket will allow the program to exit if this is the only active socket in the event system. Calling unref() will have no effect if the socket is already unrefed .*

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Node.js waits for `process.stdin` (and all other streams?) to be ended or paused before exiting. `process.stdin` is initially paused, but it resumes once `process.stdin.on()` is called. This can be solved by calling `stream.pause()`, like this:

```js
const listener = ()=>{};

process.stdin.on("data", listener);
process.stdin.off("data", listener);
process.stdin.pause();
```

Note that calling `stream.end()` has no effect because it is a readable stream.